# Divide a Chi-squared distribution by its degrees of freedom

Tags: distributions, chi-squared-distribution

Say I have random variables $X_i,\;\; i=1...5$, where $X_i \sim \chi_{1}^2$.
I understand that $S\sim \chi_{5}^2$, because $S= \sum_{i=1}^5 X_i$. However what is the distribution of $\frac{S}{5}$. Do we know it? Because I am sure that $\frac{S}{5}\sim \chi_{1}^2$ is incorrect.

Comment: What form do you need the distribution expressed in?  For instance, one standard description is "$5S$ has a $\chi^2(5)$ distribution," but in this context that's a trivial statement.

Comment: Do you mean that $5 * S\; , where S=X_1+X_2+..+X_5$ has a $\chi^2(5) $ distribution?

Comment: Yes--that's what you say in your question, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually an extemely useful distributional form for use in sampling problems.  While I'm not sure if it has a commonly used name, I call it the *scaled chi-squared distribution*, and then I always make sure to define this clearly when I'm talking about it.  In general, if $Z_1,Z_2,Z_3,... \sim \text{N}(0,1)$ is a sequence of IID standard normal random variables then we have:

$$R_n \equiv \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^2 \sim \text{ScChiSq}(n) \equiv \text{Gamma}(\text{Shape} = \tfrac{n}{2},\text{Rate} = \tfrac{n}{2}),$$

where this distribution has density function:

$$\text{ScChiSq}(r|n) = \frac{(n/2)^{n/2}}{\Gamma(\tfrac{n}{2})} \cdot r^{n/2-1} e^{-rn/2}
\quad \quad \quad \text{for all } r \geqslant 0.$$

Using the scaled chi-squared distribution directly makes it easier to present certain results in sampling theory.  This distribution has a fixed unit mean, and if $R_n \sim \text{ScChiSq}(n)$ then $R_n \rightarrow 1$ in probability as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer by myself, so I leave it here for others.

The sample mean of $n$ i.i.d. chi-squared variables of degree $k$ is distributed according to a gamma distribution with shape $\alpha$ and scale $\theta$ parameters:

$$\bar{X} =\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim Gamma(\alpha=\frac{nk}{2},\theta=\frac{2}{n}),\;\;\;\;\; where \;\; X_i\sim\chi_k^2$$